# QGIS Read COG from S3

Tags: qgis, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to read a Cloud Optimised GeoTiff (COG) from AWS S3. I can successfully run

`gdalinfo /vsis3/cog-testing/HP_COG.tif`

And see the details of the file and it says Layout: COG

But if I attempt to load the same file into QGIS 3.4 using the Data Source Manager, using the AWS S3 Protocol.

[image]

But when i try I get an error

`` Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /vsis3/cog-testing/HP_COG.tif: `/vsis3/cog-testing/HP_COG.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: /vsis3/cog-testing/HP_COG.tif ``

I am wondering if it is a region problem as my files are not the in the default region.

I have also tried using the standard HTTP protocol and also get an error.

`` Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /vsicurl/https://cog-testing.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/HP_COG.tif: `/vsicurl/https://cog-testing.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/HP_COG.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: /vsicurl/https://cog-testing.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/HP_COG.tif ``

And when I try the viscurl from my command prompt I get a 403 error.

`gdalinfo /vsicurl/https://cog-testing.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/HP_COG.tif`

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you set the correct env variables (AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=VALUE AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=VALUE AWS_S3_ENDPOINT)

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a public image in my amazon s3 bucket and when I import it to QGIS using HTTPS protocol and its URI the image upload without problem, but if I try to do it with the AWS S3 protocol and the name of the bucket and the secret key, GDAL gives an error that cannot find the file

Comment: @julsbreakdown how to do that? Where is the option in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

From the same Data Source Manager, in Raster tab, I have selected in the combobox : `HTTP/HTTPS/FTP` and as URI :

`https://cog-testing.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/HP_COG.tif`

And it works on QGIS 3.8.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 :

[image: https raster file source]

But I haven't an AWS SECRET KEY and can't investigate the `AWS3` method.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.4.10 and the HTTP/HTTPS/FTP fails as mentioned in my post. So what version are you using? I would expect the AWS to have optional AWS keys as some files can be public facing, like my file is

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

What normally works for me is:

1. Verify you have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set in either `Project menu > Properties, Variables tab` OR `QGIS Settings, Variables tab`. These values you get from AWS (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440709/how-do-i-get-aws-access-key-id-for-amazon) or ask your administrator).
2. To add a COG image, go to `Layer Menu > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer`. On the window that opens, select "Protocol..." under source type, "AWS S3" under "Type", and enter the bucket name and object key (without the bucket name)

   Meaning: `s3://bucket-name/path/to/image_cog.tif` goes to:

   - Bucket: `bucket-name`
   - Object Key: `path/to/image_cog.tif`

Like so:
[image: Example]

That's it, you be able to view you image normally now